# What are the top useful Phpstorm plugins for Magento 2 development?

Tags: magento2, php, plugin, debugging, phpstorm

1. **What are the list of useful magento2 development tools?**
2. **What are the top phpstorm useful plugins for magento2 development?**

Comment: 1. Always have a browser tab open with magento.stackexchange.com on it.

Comment: 1. Always have a browser tab open with magento.stackexchange.com on it.

Answer (score 9):

#### 1) PHPStorm with XDebug:

PHPStorm is my favorite IDE. It is an advanced IDE for PHP developers.

Many developers still use only `var_dump` and `die` to debug the system. From my experience, these techniques are not powerful. They possibility will break the application.

Magento 2 is a huge system. We should try with XDebug. With XDebug, we can see how the system works, why the exception occurs.

[image]

#### 2) PHPStorm plugins for Magento 2 development:

There are some useful PHPStorm plugins. I used two free Plugins: Magento2 and MaGinto.

[image]

There is a good paid Plugin: Magicento. You also can try.

Comment: thanks, How can i go or navigate deeper into core functionalities of magento from phpstorm

Comment: We can use the blue buttons: http://imgur.com/a/3GJd4

Answer (score 5):

[Magicento](http://magicento.com) help for development ([printscreen](https://goo.gl/8CXIMm)).

Answer (score 2):

for code standard, use PHPMD & PHPCS

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/configure-code-sniffer-for-phpstorm/

Answer (score 1):

I love PHP Inspections, probably the best plugin out there for PHPStorm.

Here are my top 5 plugins for PHPStorm:

1. PHP Inspections (EA Extended)
2. Framework Support Plugin (Symfony)
3. Key Promoter X
4. PHPUnit Enhancement
5. JetBrains Toolbox App

I've made a video showing the possibilities of each plugin: https://youtu.be/h18-RtRqHZY